# MVC 4 - update partial views

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

I have 2 sections on a page. Let's call the page index.cshtml.

The first section is the "search criteria" and the second section is the "search results"

Now, I've created the search criteria section and the search results section as partial views, and added a button at the bottom of index.cshtml, which takes the search results and calls a javascript function named "Search".

This function executes the search, that is to say it takes the search criteria input and packages it as arguments into a jQuery.get ($.get) method call.

This call then reads the response from SearchResultsController(SearchCriteria myCriteria) and uses the $.html() to replace the search results in the search results partial view.

The thing is, is this the best way to do this? Or is there a way in the MVC scaffolding where I can do it without hand rolling my own javascript or jquery or whatever other client code is flavour de jour.

All I want to do is - you click a button on page A, take the input from partial view B, and then pass that input to a stored procedure, and update the content of view C with the results of the procedure, without requiring a full page refresh. It's as simple as that.

What other ways requiring the minimum of hand-rolled code could I achieve a partial view update? Any links to code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, please don't confuse jQuery with JavaScript. jQuery is a framework that builds on JavaScript to make certain things like sending AJAX requests easier and cross-browser by default. So, yes, you can have async updates without *jQuery*, but not without *JavaScript*.

That said, this seems to be a common misunderstanding for new developers working with partial views. Partial views are merely a convenience *server-side*, meant to allow you to share similar view code between multiple views. Once your page has rendered to the client, the fact that you used partial views *does not matter at all any more*. If you want to update something on the page without initiating a page refresh, you must submit an AJAX request to fetch some new data (JSON, XML, etc.) or HTML to display, and then, also with JavaScript, use that response to render something different to the page. Again, none of this has anything to do with partial views.

Comment: Couldn't have said it better myself, and apparently I didn't lol :P

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for your reply. New developer I am not, been in this game for 17 years ;)  Let me clarify here - I know I can have async updates using javascript but the real question was, "is it *best practice* to use javascript or jquery to update the partial view" or is there another method I should try that does not need client-side code? Example, I saw in MVC there's an @ajax.BeginWebForm but how could I leverage that to update partial view B when the button pressed is on the main cshtml page? Sorry if it's confusing :)

Comment: Sorry. Didn't mean to offend. However, you seem to still be struggling with pretty basic concepts here. To update a page with new content from the server, there are two and only two options: 1) refresh the entire page with a normal GET or POST request, or 2) use AJAX to fetch the updates from the server without causing a page refresh. The `@ajax.BeginWebForm` method you mention uses AJAX to post the form, as the namespace suggests. That's *client-side* code. You may not be writing it yourself, but it's still there -- added by MVC for you. AJAX requires JavaScript. Simple as that.

Comment: Hi Chris, I realise it would require javascript, but what I'm asking is, would the best practice be for me to roll my own jscript or is there a way to do it with the framework? I could easily write my own code but if the MVC scaffolding already does it for me, I'd rather use that, not to re-invent the wheel.  Let me edit the question to make it clearer.

Comment: I'll accept the answer here even though it wasn't quite what I was getting at... thanks for your help Chris

Comment: Personally, I frown on the use of things like `@Ajax.BeginForm` because it hides functionality, and more often than not ends up being a crutch to the developer. I used to primarily program Python and one of the tenets of Python development is explicit is better than implicit. I think it's valid in any language. Additionally, it's very rare that a simple AJAX post of the a full-fledged form is what satisfies the needs of the app; the point being that you'll eventually need to move past it, anyways, so why not start it custom to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

The method you described I believe is best/cleanest/most efficient way to update your results and is a good implementation using partial views.  If you want the updates to be asynchronous you will have to use some form of javascript, but it doesn't have to be jQuery.